# How to include google login to my website

Tags: java, google-app-engine, authentication, web, google-account

I searched a lot, read many blogs, articles, tutorials, but until now did not get a working example that I could use google account to log into my application.

I know that i have to use OAuth, get tokens, autorizations, etc...

Anyone can share a example? (on GAE/JAVA)

please give me a step by step

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Users API of the App Engine. This documentation page explains it in detail:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/users/

Comment: can  you explain me step by step... is there any video tutorials for it.. pls share